# How to assign pointer to element of array of some struct in this array(OpenCL)?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, opencl, gpgpu

May be you can advise me how to create a hierarchical structure in OpenCL. It is easy if you have "new" or "malloc", but I don't know how do it in GPGPU. So I created 3 kernels:

1. To send sizeof struct to host.
2. To initialize data.
3. And kernel which uses data initialized in second kernel.

I have this struct in OpenCL:

```
    typedef struct some some;
struct some{
    char data[4];
    some* children[8];
};
```

First kernel says that size of this structure is 36 bytes(4 for data and 32 for pointers).

Next I allocate memory on GPU based on previous information and call second kernel:

```
kernel void import(global some *buffer){
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
buffer[0].data[i]=255; //For example, doesn't matter
}
//Now I need to assign pointer to next element of array(buffer) to first element
buffer[0].children[0]=&buffer[1];
}
```

But kernel not compiles. Also I tried:

```
*buffer[0].children[0]=buffer[0];
```

It compiles, but crashes of course. It is logically wrong) Without assignments of pointers everything works fine. Very cool program for 1 element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using offsets or array indices  instead of pointers.

`typedef struct some some;
struct some{
    char data[4];
    size_t children[8]; // an array of subscripts 
};`

...

`// buffer[0].children[0]=&buffer[1];  becomes
buffer[0].children[0] = 1;`

So now you can reference a child  via its subscript

```
buffer[ buffer[0].children[0] ].char[0]
```

Comment: If multiple threads can create  links   by setting the values of the children,  to ensure  consistency,  you'll  need to use atomic operations  for that.

Answer (score 0):

If your device supports OpenCL 2.0 then you can use `Shared Virtual Memory`. The pointers created on the host will be valid on the device too.

The description of `Shared Virtual Memory` concept and the examples you can find [here](http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/10/24/opencl-2-shared-virtual-memory/) and [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-20-shared-virtual-memory-overview).